# Google App Engine properties of write

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I was looking at the code from this [site](http://bukhantsov.org/2011/12/python-google-app-engine-calculator/), for a basic google app engine calculator. I am just as inexperienced with GAE as I am with HTML, so when I saw the code bellow I was a little confused. Mostly with the last line `</html>""" % (result, buttons))`. What is the % for and how does it relate result and buttons to the html code?

```
        result = ""
        try:
            result = f[operator](x, y)
        except ValueError:
            result = "Error: Incorrect Number"
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            result = "Error: Division by zero"
        except KeyError:
            pass
        # build HTML response
        buttons = "".join(["<input type='submit' name='operator' value='"
                           + o + "'>" for o in sorted(f.keys())])
        self.response.out.write("""<html>
            <body>
            <form action='/' method='get' autocomplete='off'> 
            <input type='text' name='x' value='%s'/><br/>
            <input type='text' name='y'/><br/> 
            %s 
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>""" % (result, buttons))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` is for formatting strings in Python. See a good explanation at [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html). In your example they are used to replace the '%s' characters with the values from variables.

### Modifying your example:

A modified version your example, hardcoding values of `result` and `buttons`.

```
result = "THIS IS MY RESULT"
buttons = "AND MY BUTTON"
output = """
<html>
    <body>
        <form action='/' method='get' autocomplete='off'> 
            <input type='text' name='x' value='%s'/><br/>
            <input type='text' name='y'/><br/> 
            %s 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
""" % (result, buttons)

print output
```

would yield:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action='/' method='get' autocomplete='off'> 
            <input type='text' name='x' value='THIS IS MY RESULT'/><br/>
            <input type='text' name='y'/><br/> 
            AND MY BUTTON 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your example buttons holds more Html, and format strings make more sense in a context where the values would actually change, but the above should illustrate the basic principle.

### A simpler example:

The code below:

```
result = "THIS IS MY RESULT"
buttons = "AND MY BUTTON"
print "%s ... %s!" % (result, buttons)
```

Would yield:

```
THIS IS MY RESULT ... AND MY BUTTON!
```

### How it relates to App Engine:

Both examples above say `print`: this prints the output to "stdout"—your console.

In your original example, it says `self.response.out.write`, which is how you tell App Engine to write the text (which is Html) to your browser.

Concretely, if you change:

```
result = "THIS IS MY RESULT"
buttons = "AND MY BUTTON"
print "%s ... %s!" % (result, buttons)
```

to:

```
result = "THIS IS MY RESULT"
buttons = "AND MY BUTTON"
self.response.out.write("%s ... %s!" % (result, buttons))
```

the text will appear in your browser when you visit the page instead of on the console.

### References:

[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/), also linked above is a great resource for learning Python. The whole book is good if you're new to Python. As are the [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com) courses.

The [Python documentation on format strings](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#formatstrings) is a good reference for format strings specifically.

The book ["Using Google App Engine"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801601.do) is a great resource for learning Python, Html, and App Engine all at once. I can honestly recommend it, having read it myself. It's very accessible, but it is a few years old now.

Have fun!

Comment: Oh I see, so is it placing results in value and buttons in the one before form. Or is it putting them both in both locations because it's in a tuple?

Comment: It's ordered. The first '%s' gets replaced by the first value (result's value), the second '%s' gets replaced by the second (buttons's value). I've modified the simple example to make it more clear; did it help?